# How to access to L and R channel samples of stereo audio file separately?

Tags: c, audio, wav, sampling

Suppose I have 8-bits (mono and stereo) **.wav** files.
When processing of this file I have to declare pointer to array of samples.

Suppose I create array for samples. Then if it is `mono`, I read each sample using `for(i = 0; i < n; i++ )`.

**Q: How can I access right and left channels separately (stereo)?**

**PS**

I've read a lot about "mono, stereo and *.wave" but still I can't understand how can I realise access to each channell separately...

Comment: As Roman shows, the answer to you last paragraph is Yes :)

Comment: Is the audio interleaved or not?

Comment: @Dogbert, what do you mean? 
I have several .wav files to normalize. How to normalize mono is clear because there is only one channel (I access to each sample after previous). But in stereo some difficulties appeared (how to access to the L and R channels separately?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have array of samples, the question is how you address individual values. This is how you do it:

```
const UCHAR* pnSamples = ...
if(bMono)
{
  for(INT nIndex = 0; ...)
  {
    const UCHAR nSample = pnSamples[nIndex];
    // ...
  }
} else
if(bStereo)
{
  for(INT nIndex = 0; ...)
  {
    const UCHAR nLeftSample = pnSamples[2 * nIndex + 0];
    const UCHAR nRightSample = pnSamples[2 * nIndex + 1];
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You need unsigned 8-bit integer there, `unsigned __int8` or `unsigned char` or, in Windows, it's `UCHAR`.