# Read Left and Right channel of wav file in C?

Tags: c, wav

I've created a code that reads a wavform of the wavfile and prints it out. (Read my comment in the code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

   FILE *fp = fopen("file.wav","rb");
   fseek(fp,40,SEEK_SET); // moves pointer to Subchunk2Size. Read http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/
   int length;
   fread(&length,sizeof(int),1,fp); // stores the length of the waveform to "length"
   printf("%d\n", length); 

   short *data;
   data = malloc(length*sizeof(short)); // allocate a memory with the size length*sizeof(short)
   fseek(fp,44,SEEK_SET); // moves pointer to byte 44 where data begins. again http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/
   fread(data,sizeof(short),length,fp);
   for (int k=0; k<length; k++){
      printf("data at %d is %d\n", k, data[k]);
   }
   free(data);
   return 0;
}
```

Though It can read mono wavfile (single channel). It cannot read 2 channel (Left and Right channel.)

My knowledge: 1 sample from a mono channel wav file contains 2 byte, and a 1 sample from a stereo channel wavfile contains 4 byte (2 byte from left channel and 2 byte from right channel).

Example: of a sample like:
`24 17 1E F3`

If this was a mono wav file, this will be treated as a two sample and would print, `5924` and `-3298` (note: this is little endian and F3 1E is a 2's complement as described in http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)

If this was a stereo channel wav file, it will be treated as 1 sample be printed as:

```
Sample 1 Left channel: 5924
Sample 1 Right channel: -3298
```

So `24 17` is the sample of the left and `1E F3` of the right.
This is my interpretation of http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

I'm searching for an answer that would put Left channel to `short Left[]` and Right channel to `short Right[]`

Comment: It is my understanding that mono files are single channel and stereo files are dual channel. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569859/how-to-access-to-l-and-r-channel-samples-of-stereo-audio-file-separately?rq=1) may be helpful.

Comment: Your interpretation of that documentation sounds correct to me. But `f31e` is to be interpreted as a 2s complement negative number, that is -3298 and not +62238

Comment: Aside:When reading a file format, it is a good time to use `uint16_t, uint32_t` etc. rather than `short, int`..  Printing in hex may also be useful.

Comment: @jabber Yeah I totally forgotten about that. I check once again and you're correct

Answer (score 1):

After racking my head a couple of times, I think I finally get it right (Read my comments).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

short * stereoChannel;

short * leftChannel;
short * rightChannel;

char    Subchunk2[4];
int     move    =    0;
short   channel =    1;
int     val     =    50000;

int main(){

   FILE *fp = fopen("bin.wav","rb");
   if (!fp){
      printf("Couldn't open file!\n");
      return 0;
   }
   while (1){
     fseek(fp,36+move,SEEK_SET);
     fread(Subchunk2,4*sizeof(char),1,fp);
     if (!strcmp(Subchunk2,"data")){
        break;
     }
     move++;
   }
   fseek(fp,22,SEEK_SET);
   fread(&channel,sizeof(short),1,fp);
   fseek(fp,36+move+4,SEEK_SET);
   int num;
   fread(&num,sizeof(int),1,fp);
   stereoChannel = malloc(num*sizeof(short));
   fseek(fp,4,SEEK_CUR);
   fread(stereoChannel,sizeof(short),num,fp);
   if (channel == 2){
      val=0;
      printf("wavfile in stereo\n");
      leftChannel = malloc(num*sizeof(short)/2);
      rightChannel = malloc(num*sizeof(short)/2);
      int channelpoint = 0;
      for (int inc=0;inc<num/2;inc++){
         leftChannel[channelpoint] = stereoChannel[inc*2];
         rightChannel[channelpoint] = stereoChannel[(inc*2)+1];
         channelpoint++;
      }



      for (int k=0; k<50000; k++){
         printf("stereo sample %d L: %d R: %d \n",k,leftChannel[k],rightChannel[k]);
      }

      free(rightChannel);
      free(leftChannel);
   }
   for (int k=0; k<val; k++){  // If this is stereo, it would print nothing because val was set to 0
      printf("mono sample %d is %d\n", k, stereoChannel[k]);
}
   free(stereoChannel);
   return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
...
stereo sample 49981 L: 8039 R: 6943
stereo sample 49982 L: 9277 R: 10518
stereo sample 49983 L: 13398 R: 16936
stereo sample 49984 L: 13305 R: 15692
stereo sample 49985 L: 2715 R: 9778
stereo sample 49986 L: -5680 R: 5595
stereo sample 49987 L: -3632 R: 3921
...
```

Explanation for the `while loop`. This code checks for the `data` tag because not every wavfile data tag begins at offset 36.  (Maybe I should add a function that checks if the file is a wavfile because without it, this would loop forever and may cause segmentation fault.)

Give me your thoughts.